# How to add javascript files to liferay-portlet.xml in liferay project

Tags: javascript, liferay-6, portlet

I'm developing an application with liferay 6.0.6 and want to add javascript files to my portlet. If I have two or three javascript files, how could I add them?

So here is my liferay-portlet.xml :

```
<portlet>
  <portlet-name>portletName</portlet-name>
  <icon>/icon.png</icon>
  <instanceable>true</instanceable>
  <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
  <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
  <css-class-wrapper>portletName-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<portlet>
  <portlet-name>portletName</portlet-name>
  <icon>/icon.png</icon>
  <instanceable>true</instanceable>
  <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
  <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
  <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/view.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
  <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/controler.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
  <css-class-wrapper>portletName-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

For details see the xml schema definition: http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd

Comment: thanks mark i think it will work according to dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd,i will test it :)